# Is nikah nullified by jokingly saying to my husband we are done?

Tags: nikah, talaq

I am really upset because I jokingly said to my husband that we are done with each other, we don't have any relationship. Does this nullify my nikah? My husband says it's a form of kenAya divorce.  Can you please explain?

Comment: Talaq can only be pronounced by the husband. But note that matters of marriage and divorce are too seriouse to joke about.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: "Actions are buy by intention" *انما الاعمال بالنیات* so no, it's not nullified

Comment: The question needs more information. There is no joking allowed in matters of marriage, divorce, and taking back of a wife during _'iddah_. If there was a _tafwīd_ or _wikāla_ from the husband, then you may be divorced (but more information will be needed). If there was a _tafwīd_ or _wikāla_, were they done during the same sitting as when you said your phrase in question (differs by the school of jurisprudence)? If there was a _tafwīd_ or _wikāla_ done in another setting, were they done prior to or during or after the marriage contract? More information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

There's various forms of [divorce in Islam](http://Divorce%20in%20Islam):

- [*Talaq*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divorce_in_Islam#Talaq_(repudiation)) is initiated by the husband, so this is not talaq.
- [*Khul*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divorce_in_Islam#Khul%CA%BF_(mutual_divorce)) requires your husband's agreement, and a (re)payment from the wife to the husband (usually the mahr amount), so this is not khul.

A wife saying "we are done" does not amount to divorce.

See [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/en/article/92752/divorce-in-islam) for more details about these types of divorces.

Answer (score -3):

Marriage is one of the things where even jokingly given talaq becomes effective. (H). Provided the sense is clear in the expression and meanings. Therefore, Muslims have to be very careful in this regard.(intention here is not relevant).

This penalty, most probably, is made effective, to impress upon Muslims the sanctity of the Marriage. Saying that you can't just fool around with this sacred contract.